# Crop an image in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, image, crop

I am working on asp.net using c#. I have to adjust an image by taking a portion of that image.
I want to crop a portion of image from middle like in the below image.

[image]

can anyone help me please.

Comment: What have you tried? Why don't you try a google search? http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by getting co-ordinates of the image's portion by Jquery.

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $('#target').Jcrop({
            onChange: showCoords,
            onSelect: showCoords,
            onRelease: clearCoords
        });
    });
    function showCoords(c) {
        $('#xaxis').val(c.x);
        $('#yaxis').val(c.y);
        $('#x2').val(c.x2);
        $('#y2').val(c.y2);
        $('#xwidth').val(c.w);
        $('#div_width').val(c.w);
        $('#yheight').val(c.h);
        $('#div_height').val(c.h);
    };
    function clearCoords() {
        $('#coords input').val('0');
        $('#yheight').css({ color: 'red' });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#yheight').css({ color: 'inherit' });
        }, 500);
    };
```

Then I used these co-ordinates to crop image in C# like

```
String savedFileName = uploadProfileImage(profileImageName, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Int32.Parse(xaxis), Int32.Parse(yaxis), Int32.Parse(xwidth), Int32.Parse(yheight)));

public String uploadProfileImage(string profileImageName, System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        try
        {
            String retFileName = "";
            if (profileImageName != null || profileImageName != "")
            {
                GenerateCroppedThumbNail(profileImageName, rectangle);
            }
            return retFileName;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

That works fine

Comment: What does GenerateCroppedThumbNail do? Why don't you display that as part of your answer as it seems to be the most important part

Comment: I agree with @link64

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it on the server, I suggest using [a server-safe wrapper](http://imageresizing.net) instead of using System.Drawing directly, [so you don't have to worry about avoiding the 29+ pitfalls and bugs](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/).

My [ImageResizing.Net library offers both automatic and manual cropping](http://imageresizing.net/)

**Automatic**

```
new ImageJob(source,dest,new 
 ResizeSettings("width=200;height=200;mode=crop;anchor=middlecenter")).Build();
```

**Manual (by percentages)**

```
new ImageJob(source,dest,new 
 ResizeSettings("crop=20,20,80,80;cropxunits=100;cropyunits=100")).Build();
```

**Manual (in source image coordinates)**

```
new ImageJob(source,dest,new 
 ResizeSettings("crop=200,200,1000,1000;")).Build()
```